How to display POIs (places) on google maps flutter
I'm using google maps flutter package and I successfully displayed the map on the screen/ However when using maptype as normal, all the points POIs are shown clearly but the moment I switch maptype to satellite, the points disappear. How to show the points POIs in satellite view?
PS. cloudMapId is totally usesless even though the device on the latest renderer initialized
class GoogleMapView extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const GoogleMapView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(
      () => GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(40.75757531, -70.99141428),
          zoom: 14,
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
        mapType: MapType.satellite,
        cloudMapId:
            'ejwfewjmofmewf', 
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController googleMapController) async {
          controller.googleMapController = googleMapController;
          await controller.onMapCreated();
        },
        onCameraMove: (CameraPosition cameraPosition) {},
        onCameraIdle: () {},
        myLocationEnabled: controller.isLocationGranted.value,
        markers: const {},
        zoomControlsEnabled: false,
        myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
        trafficEnabled: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}


Are you using an emulator or a physical device in testing your app? Please make sure that the emulator have a Google Play available or that you update your Google Play Services to make sure that you'r running on the New Map Renderer

Thank you for your reply. I ran the app on both physical device and an emulator. The device is running on the latest map renderer. I have made sure of that.
